# How a manager could approve the request of his employees only

Tags: odoo-11

I have many managers in the same department and i want that every manager see and approve the requests of his own employees only. How can i resolve this problem ? Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution i add a record rule with the domain filter

```
[ '|',('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id),('employee_id.parent_id.user_id','=',user.id)]
```

and it works

Answer (score 1):

we can add the manager in the employee master.Add this condition to check whether he is manager or not employee_id.parent_id.user_id.id = self._uid if this condition satisfy he can approve the request other wise raise a warning.